# controller isnt working as it is supposed to

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, passport.js

I used MVC to make a NodeJS server and this is one of the controllers:

```
module.exports.create_user = async function (req, res) {
    // console.log(req.body);
    // console.log(req.user);
    await Company.findOne({ user: req.body.user }, function (err, user) {
        if (user) {
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        else {
            if (req.body.password == req.body.confirm_password) {
                Company.create({
                    "country": req.body.country,
                    "username": req.body.user,
                    "password": req.body.password
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log('Passwords didnt match');
            }
        }
    });
    req.session.save(() => {
        return res.redirect('/profile');
    })
}
```

What this code supposed to do?

It searches if a user already exists; if yes, it will redirect to `/login`.
If no such user exists, it should create a new user and redirect to `/profile`.

What does this code do?

Regardless of whether the user exists or not, the code always redirects to /login. Also, a user is created in the database, so every time a new user wants to signup, the user needs to signup and then go to sign in to get access to `/profile`

What is the problem here which doesn't allow redirect to `/profile`? And how to fix it?
Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I don't think you can use `await` and `callbacks` both in the user find query. Please check the library docs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
passport.checkAuthentication = async function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    let auth_status = await req.isAuthenticated() ? "sucess" : "failure";
    console.log(`Authentication ${auth_status}`);
    // if the user is signed in, then pass on the request to the next function(controller's action)
    if (await req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }

    // if the user is not signed in
    return res.redirect('/login');
}
```

I did a but more work on this and possibly the controller is working fine and the problem could be in middleware. In the signup case discussed above, the middelware always logs 'Authentication failure' to console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `username` instead of `user` to find a user

```
Company.findOne({ username: req.body.user });
```

You are mixing `callback` style with `async/await`, `await` keyword does not affect on your, it will not wait until the query finished. `await` keyword just working when you wait for a `Promise like object` (`then` able object).

I guess you are using `mongoose`, the current version of `mongoose` supports Promise return style.

```
module.exports.create_user = async function (req, res) {
  // console.log(req.body);
  // console.log(req.user);
  try {
    // Use `username` instead of `user` to find a user
    const user = await Company.findOne({ username: req.body.user }); // callback is not passed, it will return a Promise

    if (user) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }

    if (req.body.password == req.body.confirm_password) {
      await Company.create({ // wait until user is created
        "country": req.body.country,
        "username": req.body.user,
        "password": req.body.password
      });

      // then redirect page
      req.session.save(() => {
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Passwords didnt match');
      // what happen when password didn't match
      // return res.redirect('/login'); ???
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // something went wrong
    // return res.redirect('/login'); ???
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! that was the perfect ans which I needed :D

Comment: wait its still giving the same bug. I have given the updated code in next ans

Comment: @KrushnalPatel still `'Passwords didn\'t match'`?

Comment: no the passwords were never the problem cus after the controller is executed the data is added to MongoDB. The controller is working fine but the only problem is in redirecting to `/profile`. In a ideal case `await Company.create()` should be executed and then user should get logged in and redirected to `/profile` but instead is getting redirected to '/login`. I also have a middleware, please check if that's creating the bug (posting the middleware as an answer)